# Where did i find AndroidManifest.xml file in React Native Expo file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Where did i find `AndroidManifest.xml` file in React Native Expo file for requesting permissions?

There is any other ways to request permission from user?

Answer (score 0):

add `permissions` array inside your `app.json` like this

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Page",

   ...

    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false
    },
    "android":{
      "permissions":["READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"],
      "package":"com.example.app"
    }
  }
}
```

So your app.json should be

```js
    "android":{
      "permissions":["READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"],
      "package":"com.example.app"
    }
```

Comment: I can't able to add permission in app.json. This app is built using expo

Comment: If you need to customization in your native size `android/ios` then you need to `expo eject` then you seen you `android/ios` under expo project

Comment: @ShyamaprasadK I am aware that you are using Expo. check answer now add it like this in your ```app.json```. Expo handles all native configuration in ```app.json```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, EXPO is a tool and provides tools to create a React-native app, When you create an app using EXPO there is no android/ios folder/project inside the react-native expo project if you need to add `permissions` in `Android/iOS` just update/Change you
`app.json / app.config.js`

update your `app.config.js` to look like

```
export default {
  expo: {

    android: {
  
      permissions: ["ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION", "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"],
      config: {
        googleMaps: {
          apiKey: "...abc...",
        },
      },
    }
  },
};
```

You also check this official site for more info regarding this
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#permissions